# Draw route on marker touch - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

In the app i'm building i'm using a mapView with markers on it,
i want that whenever the user touches a marker, a route will be drawn between the user and the marker. How can i do that?

Comment: מתן, רק שתדע, פה זה לא המקום לשאול 'איך עושים את זה'. אני מופתע שאף אחד עוד לא קפץ.
כאן זה המקום לשאול שאלות כשנתקעת במשהו ספציפי.. סתם שתדע

Comment: אני לא מחפש תשובה ספציפית, מחפש רק המלצות. אני תקוע כבר יומיים על בעיה ,קטנה מאוד בתוך זה. חישוב המסלול ואיתור הלחיצה על המרקר כבר קיימים, כל מה שחסר לי זה דרך להעביר את מיקום המרקר שעליו לחצו אל האקטיביטי. אני כבר שאלתי על העניין הספציפי הזה, אך אף אחד לא ענה ולכן החלטתי לפרסם את השאלה הזו.

Comment: אוקיי, אז עצה לייעול, אף אחד לא יודע איך מימשת את זה, אתה צריך להראות את הקטעי קוד הרלוונטיים. איך אתה מאתר את הלחיצה על המרקר? לאיזה אקטיביטי אתה רוצה להעביר אותה, וכו'. אי אפשר להבין מהשאלה, כמו שהיא כרגע, שאתה מבקש משהו ספציפי.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find marker's latitude & longitude .
2. [Then Draw the route between your current geopoint & marker's geopoint](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html)